# Ios app and unity as library module Arcore based crash

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, arcore

I have my iOS MyApp , using Firebase, and I have to integrate a "Unity as library" module, based on ARCore Geospatial

I have built it trying a lot of different strategies , but no matter what I did , at runtime it log a lot of Firebase conflict and then crash as for the log extract below

The Unity frameworks run smooth when run as alone

If I remove Firebase from MyApp everything also run fine, (but of course I can't  remove Firebase on production release)

Anyone else around got the same issue?

Many error like this

```
objc[8956]: Class FIRInstallationsErrorUtil is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE0FB4F1-DFB7-4A15-8781-DE1336275BEA/Loquis.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x10bcbd960) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE0FB4F1-DFB7-4A15-8781-DE1336275BEA/Loquis.app/Loquis (0x101cd0c38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[8956]: Class FIRInstallationsHTTPError is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE0FB4F1-DFB7-4A15-8781-DE1336275BEA/Loquis.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x10bcbd988) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE0FB4F1-DFB7-4A15-8781-DE1336275BEA/Loquis.app/Loquis (0x101cd0c60). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

then ...

```
10.19.1 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` to your application initialization. This can be done in in the App Delegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI).
```

and finally it crash with this

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282f7ed30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x198194870 0x1904b3c00 0x19822519c 0x1980d9ff8 0x19821ab10 0x1096bc7ec 0x1096bbf8c 0x1096596b4 0x1038e4f50 0x1038e6b34 0x1038eeba4 0x1038ef728 0x1038fc5f8 0x1038fbc2c 0x201b05964 0x201b05a04)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282f7ed30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x198194870 0x1904b3c00 0x19822519c 0x1980d9ff8 0x19821ab10 0x1096bc7ec 0x1096bbf8c 0x1096596b4 0x1038e4f50 0x1038e6b34 0x1038eeba4 0x1038ef728 0x1038fc5f8 0x1038fbc2c 0x201b05964 0x201b05a04)
[0x125f6c800] Created session
[0x0] Releasing session
[0x125f6c800] Releasing session
Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: -[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282f7ed30
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019819487c B37A1273-B0C2-312E-9E0B-7143FB645C69 + 968828
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001904b3c00 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019822519c B37A1273-B0C2-312E-9E0B-7143FB645C69 + 1560988
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001980d9ff8 B37A1273-B0C2-312E-9E0B-7143FB645C69 + 204792
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019821ab10 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
    5   UnityFramework                      0x00000001096bc7ec -[GDTCCTUploadOperation updateNextUploadTimeWithResponse:forTarget:] + 52
    6   UnityFramework                      0x00000001096bbf8c __54-[GDTCCTUploadOperation uploadBatch:toTarget:storage:]_block_invoke + 56
    7   UnityFramework                      0x00000001096596b4 __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.18 + 52
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001038e4f50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001038e6b34 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001038eeba4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1368
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001038ef728 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001038fc5f8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 328
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001038fbc2c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 444
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000201b05964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000201b05a04 start_wqthread + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

objc[8956]: Class _TtGCs18_DictionaryStorageSSGV20FirebaseCoreInternal13WeakContainerCS0_16HeartbeatStorage__$ is implemented in both ?? (0x13b525b28) and /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1e91273a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: How have you added Firebase? It seems as though two instances of it in your project may be referenced? In addition to the first debug guide posted by @Moiz Hassnet, consider [removing Firebase from your project and updating it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/troubleshooting-faq#update-sdk-version) as this may correct some of the installation issues.

Comment: that's exact... the problem comes from two Firebase , one from my iOS app , other from UnityFramework that use arcore , and then,  as dependency, Firebase... given the integration as described here , you get duplicated symbols .... https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary-iOS.html

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Firebase is initialized before you attempt to use any Firebase services in your app.
Useful links for Debugging
https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/build-debug-guide
https://medium.com/firebase-developers/debugging-firebase-functions-in-vs-code-a1caf22db0b2

Comment: I have iOS MyApp using Firebase and want to add a "Unity as library Arcore module" ...that's seems not possible ... see https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-ios-sdk/issues/95